# scala: Why does scala allow implementing a function literal with Map/List/etc

Tags: java, scala

I defined a scala trait like this:

```
trait Example {
  def func: Int => Int
}
```

And the compiler allows me to implement it by:

```
class SomeClass extends Example {
   def func = Map(1->2, 3->4)
}
```

I can replace the `Map` with `List` it will still work. My question is: Why? didn't I declare `func` as a function literal that needs to be implemented as a function?

On a deeper level, how does scala's compiler check for function signatures?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Int => Int` desugers to `Function1[Int, Int]`. Both `Map[K, V]` and `List[A]` extend the `Function1[A, B]` trait as part of their collection hierarchy, and that's why the compiler allows these types as a concrete implementation.

For example, Map:

```
trait MapLike[K, +V, +This <: MapLike[K, V, This] with Map[K, V]] extends PartialFunction[K, V]
```

Where `PartialFunction[K, V]` extends `Function1[K, V]`